# Git inside virtual machine does not work

Tags: git, macos, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine in VMWare Fusion running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Mac.
I need ubuntu for development. The code which I am developing on is in a git repo and I need that repo both in the Mac OS and Ubuntu. In order not to have several versions of the repo, I want to simply have it on the Mac OS and use it in Ubuntu through a shared folder.
I have the shared folder set up and can read and write to the files in the git repo from Ubuntu. Unfortunately, git itself does not work properly in Ubuntu when I am in the shared folder. This also prevents me from building the code in the git repo, the invoked `make` command does some git stuff (submodules etc).

For example, I can't clone a git repo into the shared folder from ubuntu, even though I have write access to the shared folder.

```
$ cd shared_folder
$ touch test # works
$ git clone https://github.com/ATLFlight/cross_toolchain.git
Cloning into 'cross_toolchain'...
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The repository in question is public and cloning both in mac and in ubuntu (somewhere not in the shared folder) works fine.

In a repo (which I cloned in a mac terminal) with several submodules, even `git status` fails, apparently because there are some hardcoded paths which don't make sense in the Ubuntu context.

What is the recommended approach of working with git repos in virtual machines without having duplicate code?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I've set up my workflow s.t. I don't need this on a regular basis anymore. But I have figured out that at least `git status` can work with some symlinks in the virtual machine. E.g. if the git repo lives in `/User/myname/repo` on the mac, I created a symlink in ubuntu of that path to the path that the repo is in as seen by ubuntu. It's possible that with this you can get everything else to work as well, but I haven't tried.